# Wordpress Query and Get_Post_Meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below code on one of my pages.  This page is showing 100 queries when I use 
`echo get_num_queries()`.  I am trying reduce the amount of queries but I am having trouble finding where they are all coming from.

The only thing I could figure is the `get_post_meta`.  Does get_post_meta run a query each time? If so is there a better way to do this so I don't run a query each time?

```
<?php
/*  This is the second wordpress loop which will show only non paid dealers per the above wp_query in query_single.  The 0 passed is non-paid dealers*/

     query_single('dealers', 'draft', '0', $taxtype,  $value);
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
$address=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-street_address', TRUE);
$city=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-city', TRUE);
$state=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-state_abbreviation', TRUE);
$zip=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-zip_code', TRUE);
$phone=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-phone_number', TRUE);
$paid=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-paid', TRUE);
$post_id=get_the_ID();
get_each_dealer_brand($post_id);?>

<ul class="ullisting">
<?php
if($paid==0) {

    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\"><strong>";the_title();echo "</strong></p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">$address | $city, $state $zip</p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">P: $phone</p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"listing\"><span><small>$brands_list</small></span></p></li>";
} 
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce your query count by calling get_post_meta once - it will grab all of the relevant fields:

```
// will have all of your fields and more in an array, with fewer queries called
$post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
var_dump($post_meta);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta